# Preemptible instances for an existing VM - Google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to make an existing VM provisioned from bitnami a preemptible instance in the compute instances.

I can't do it from the console as the option is greyed out for me.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One minor clarification: it's not possible to change the preemptible status of a VM *after creation*, regardless of whether it's actually running or not.

Comment: It is 2018 already. Do you know, if anything has changed in preemptible status?

Comment: is there a way to convert preemptible VM into regular VM somehow?

Comment: Save the instance as a machine image and recreate the instance from the machine image.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to change the preemptible status of a running VM.

A VM is determined to be preemptible or normal at creation time, and can't be upgraded or downgraded once created.

Comment: is Preemptible instance can be detele data?

Answer (score 1):

A near solution may be: You can make a new preemptible instance much like the original, and then move the virtual disk over to the new one, I believe.

Boot it up and you've pretty much achieved what you want, unless you have considerable Compute Engine config that you would have to duplicate.

I believe you can also perhaps take a snapshot of the original VM, and create a duplicate that IS preemptible.

But these are all workarounds of course...

Comment: Taking a snapshot and then launching a new VM does the trick.